# Not able to capture HTML from the browser for Android

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am trying to capture HTML code response from browser. I have created a browser and trying to capture HTML content and print in logcat.
I am getting following error message in logcat:

> 01-28 13:36:18.914 4079-4079/com.aseelarbazanny.myweb D/PocketMagic: onPageFinished
>   01-28 13:36:18.954 4079-4079/com.aseelarbazanny.myweb I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'showHTML'", source: http://www.pocketmagic.net/ (1)

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidBrowserGUI extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // constants
    final static String     LOG_TAG         = "PocketMagic";

    final static int        idTopLayout     = Menu.FIRST + 100,
            idBack          = Menu.FIRST + 101,
            idBotLayout     = Menu.FIRST + 102,
            idAddr          = Menu.FIRST + 103,
            idButBack       = Menu.FIRST + 104,
            idButFwd        = Menu.FIRST + 105,
            idButReload     = Menu.FIRST + 106,
            idButStop       = Menu.FIRST + 107,
            idButGo         = Menu.FIRST + 108;

    // interface controls
    String                  m_szPage    = "http://www.pocketmagic.net";
    int                     m_nHTMLSize = 0;
    WebView                 m_web;

    EditText m_etAddr;

    TextView m_tv;

    Button m_bButBack, m_bButFwd, m_bButReload, m_bButStop, m_bButGo;
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Hide titlebar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Create our top content holder
        RelativeLayout global_panel = new RelativeLayout (this);
        global_panel.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        global_panel.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
        global_panel.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.back));
        // +++++++++++++ TOP COMPONENT: the header
        RelativeLayout ibMenu = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ibMenu.setId(idTopLayout);
        ibMenu.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line));
        int ibMenuPadding = (int) 6;
        ibMenu.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        global_panel.addView(ibMenu,topParams);
        //
        int nTextH =  12;
        // go button
        m_bButGo = new Button(this);
        m_bButGo.setId(idButGo);
        m_bButGo.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        m_bButGo.setText("Go");
        m_bButGo.setTextSize(nTextH);
        m_bButGo.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpb5 =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpb5.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        lpb5.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        ibMenu.addView(m_bButGo, lpb5);
        // address field
        m_etAddr = new EditText(this);
        m_etAddr.setId(idAddr);
        m_etAddr.setText(m_szPage);
        nTextH =  12;
        m_etAddr.setTextSize(nTextH);
        m_etAddr.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpbEdit =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpbEdit.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idButGo);
        lpbEdit.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        ibMenu.addView(m_etAddr, lpbEdit);

        // +++++++++++++ BOTTOM COMPONENT: the footer
        RelativeLayout ibMenuBot = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ibMenuBot.setId(idBotLayout);
        ibMenuBot.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line));
        ibMenuBot.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams botParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        botParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        global_panel.addView(ibMenuBot,botParams);
        m_bButBack = new Button(this);
        m_bButBack.setId(idButBack);
        m_bButBack.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        m_bButBack.setText("Back");
        m_bButBack.setTextSize(nTextH);
        m_bButBack.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpb1 =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpb1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        lpb1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        ibMenuBot.addView(m_bButBack, lpb1);
        // fwd button
        m_bButFwd = new Button(this);
        m_bButFwd.setId(idButFwd);
        m_bButFwd.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        m_bButFwd.setText("Fwd");
        m_bButFwd.setTextSize(nTextH);
        m_bButFwd.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpb2 =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpb2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idButBack);
        lpb2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        ibMenuBot.addView(m_bButFwd, lpb2);
        // reload button
        m_bButReload = new Button(this);
        m_bButReload.setId(idButReload);
        m_bButReload.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        m_bButReload.setText("Rld");
        m_bButReload.setTextSize(nTextH);
        m_bButReload.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpb3 =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpb3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idButFwd);
        lpb3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        ibMenuBot.addView(m_bButReload, lpb3);
        // stop button
        m_bButStop = new Button(this);
        m_bButStop.setId(idButStop);
        m_bButStop.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        m_bButStop.setText("Stop");
        m_bButStop.setTextSize(nTextH);
        m_bButStop.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpb4 =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpb4.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idButReload);
        lpb4.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        ibMenuBot.addView(m_bButStop, lpb4);
        // status
        m_tv = new TextView(this);
        m_tv.setText("Status");
        m_tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        m_tv.setTextSize(nTextH);
        m_tv.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTV = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpcTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idButStop);
        lpcTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        ibMenuBot.addView(m_tv, lpcTV);

        // +++++++++++++ MIDDLE COMPONENT: only a webview control
        m_web = new WebView(this);
        m_web.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams midParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        midParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,ibMenuBot.getId());
        midParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,ibMenu.getId());
        global_panel.addView(m_web,midParams );
        // Configure our webview object
        m_web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        m_web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        // set starting page
        if (m_szPage != null) m_web.loadUrl(m_szPage);
        // set java script used to get the HTML code

        m_web.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

        // Interface READY
        setContentView(global_panel);
    }

    // Used with Webview, to get the HTML code
    class JavaScriptInterface{
        public void showHTML(String html) {
            m_nHTMLSize = 0;
            if (html !=null) {
                //int i = html.lastIndexOf(""); //search for something in the text
                m_nHTMLSize = html.length();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "HTML content is: "+html+"\nSize:"+m_nHTMLSize+" bytes");

            }
        }
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPageStarted");
            m_tv.setText("Loading page...");
            //stop button is enabled only when pages are loading
            m_bButStop.setEnabled(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPageFinished");
            m_tv.setText("Ready");
            //stop button is disabled when pages are already loaded
            m_bButStop.setEnabled(false);
            // This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading.
            m_web.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
            // adjust prev/next buttons, only if history is available
            m_bButBack.setEnabled(m_web.canGoBack());
            m_bButFwd.setEnabled(m_web.canGoForward());


        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = arg0.getId();

        // If cancel is pressed, close our app
        if (id == idBack) finish();

        if (id == idButGo) {
            m_szPage = m_etAddr.getText().toString();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Go for page:"+m_szPage);
            if (m_szPage != null) m_web.loadUrl(m_szPage);
        }

        if (id == idButBack) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Go back");
            m_web.goBack();
        }
        if (id == idButFwd) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Go forward");
            m_web.goForward();
        }

        if (id == idButReload) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Reload page");
            m_web.reload();
        }

        if (id == idButStop) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Stop loading page");
            m_web.stopLoading();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, only methods explicitly marked with the [@JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) annotation are available to the Javascript code.

You just need to add this above your `showHTML` method e.g:

```
class JavaScriptInterface{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) {
        m_nHTMLSize = 0;
        if (html !=null) {
            //int i = html.lastIndexOf(""); //search for something in the text
            m_nHTMLSize = html.length();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "HTML content is: "+html+"\nSize:"+m_nHTMLSize+" bytes");

        }
    }
}
```

Also need to remove `window` from you JS call:

```
m_web.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
```

to

```
m_web.loadUrl("javascript:HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
```